# Referencing an object attribute by a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to DRY up a method in which I need to perform the same task on three different attributes. Like this:

```
if !@item.picture.blank?
  picture_copy = Picture.new
  picture_copy.save!
  item_copy.picture = picture_copy
end

if !@item.picture_for_x.blank?
  picture_for_x_copy = PictureForX.new
  picture_for_x_copy.save!
  item_copy.picture_for_x = picture_for_x_copy
end

if !@item.picture_for_y.blank?
  picture_for_y_copy = PictureForY.new
  picture_for_y_copy.save!
  item_copy.picture_for_y = picture_for_y_copy
end
```

So basically I'm running the same code, but instantiating different objects and then assigning them to different attributes. It feels like there should be a way to DRY up this view using reflection. Is there a way that I can refer to these attributes and objects as strings passed into a helper method?

For various reasons, I can't just use .clone or .dup: mainly because there's binary file pointers involved and I also need deep copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{
  picture:       Picture,
  picture_for_x: PictureForX,
  picture_for_y: PictureForY
}.each do |name,klass|
  if !@item.send(name).blank?
    copy = klass.new
    copy.save!
    item_copy.send("#{name}=",copy)
  end
end
```

Remember that in Ruby there *are* no properties or attributes available externally, just methods (which you may choose to call without parentheses so that it *looks* like you're accessing a property, and which sometimes might be just returning the value of an instance variable).

[`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send) is the magic method that lets you invoke a method based on a name stored in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
def picture_for_x_blank?(s = "")
  s = "_for_#{s}" unless s.empty?
  m = "picture#{s}"

  unless @item.send(m).blank?
    copy = Kernel::const_get(m.camelize).new
    copy.save!
    item_copy.send("#{m}=", copy)
  end
end

picture_for_x_blank?
picture_for_x_blank?("x")
picture_for_x_blank?("y")
```